# 'Official' CUDA Reduction function can't accept certain numbers?

Tags: c++, cuda

currently trying to use the Reduction #3 outline in the CUDA pdf [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).

Here is how my Reduction function looks

```
template <typename T>
__device__ void offsetReduction(planet<T> *bodies, T *outdata, int arrayIdent, int nbodies){
    extern __shared__ T sdata[];

    unsigned int tID = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = tID + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (arrayIdent == 1){
        if (i < nbodies){
            sdata[tID] = bodies[i].vx * bodies[i].mass;
        }

        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (arrayIdent == 2){
        if (i < nbodies){
            sdata[tID] = (bodies[i].vy * bodies[i].mass);
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (arrayIdent == 3){
        if (i < nbodies){
            sdata[tID] = (bodies[i].vz * bodies[i].mass);
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    for (unsigned int stride = blockDim.x / 2; stride > 0; stride >>=1)
    {
        if (tID < stride)
        {
            sdata[tID] += sdata[tID + stride];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (tID == 0)
    {
        outdata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    }
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working correctly so I did some calculations.

I launch the same number of threads as 'int nbodies', and in my case I have chosen 5. So each of the 5 threads comes in and adds a value to sdata[] no problem. However once it gets to the addition part it goes wrong.

On the first iteration Thread 0 accesses sdata[3], Thread 1 accesses sdata[4] and the other threads do nothing. On the second iteration Thread 0 accesses sdata[1](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) and the other threads do nothing. The addition is then 'finished' and the kernel finishes. But sdata[2] is never added so I get an incorrect value stored at sdata[0].

Am I missing something really obvious? (I have been staring at this for a while so I probably have.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any tree like reduction will only work for a power of two threads per block

Comment: @talonmies I was thinking that but I wasn't sure if I was just missing something else. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: So that was whole your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reduction code, like any other "tree-like" reduction operation, requires that the number of threads that participate in the shared memory reduction be equal to a power of 2 to work correctly.

Note that means you *could* design a reduction kernel which would run correctly for any *multiple* of 2 threads per block by having the nearest smaller power of 2 threads perform the actual reduction. The code you have posted cannot, however, work like that.